# Is there anything available to display error code in luman laravel while file uploading to validated the file size and file type?

Tags: php, web-services, file, file-upload, laravel-5

Am new for **luman laravel** framework and i worked with file uploading concept with file type and file size validation.

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'profile_picture' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:100',
            'pancard_image' => 'required|mimes:pdf,jpeg,png,jpg|max:100',
            'national_id_image' => 'required|mimes:pdf,jpeg,png,jpg|max:100',
            'income_proof_image' => 'required|mimes:pdf,jpeg,png,jpg,doc,docs,xlsx|max:100',
            'address_proof_image' => 'required|mimes:pdf,jpeg,png,jpg|max:100'
        ]);
```

Am using the validation with above code and my question is how can i display error message with error code like core php file uploading concept.suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2):

in the controller

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
if ($validator->fails())
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
```

in the blade:

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $message)
        <li>{{ $message }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: As per your suggestion ,i edited my code and but i want executed in the postman.

Comment: is your FileController extents the Controller

Comment: ya here my controller `class FileController extends Controller
{
  
public function saveFile(Request $request)
    {



        $borrower_id=$request->input('borrower_id');


       $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
 'profile_picture' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:100'
]);



if ($validator->fails())
{
     $message = $validator->errors();
            $this->setStatusCode(404);
            return $this->RespondWithError($message);


      
}
else
{`